# Label expression that parses a multi-sentence label so that every 5 words show up on a new line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have long notes that I have to put on the map. My method is to add the notes to the attribute table and display them as labels. I'm having a hard time writing a label expression that parses the sentences so that every 5 words show up on a new line.

This solution I found on the internet only parses the label into two lines, I can't figure out how to make it work for multiple lines:

```
left([Labels_for] ,instr(50, [Labels_for] ," ")) & vbnewline & right([Labels_for] ,len([Labels_for] )-(instr(20, [Labels_for] ," ")))
```

Comment: Do you have the Maplex labeling extension turned on? That has an [option](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/stacking-labels-about-stacking-labels.htm) for automatically stacking labels that are too long, no need to write your own code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've never tried the Maplex before, so it's useful to know it exists. I turned it on in the data frame properties and it froze/crashed my ArcMap. I will try it on a smaller map next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change lable language to python and try:

```
def FindLabel ( [textfield] ):
    text = [textfield].split()
    n = 5
    text = '\r\n'.join([' '.join(text[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(text),n)])
    return text
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as I wanted! I appreciate your screenshot, the Advanced checkbox is key.